# concatenate an increment counter onto the end of an array selector within a json response loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

so I'm looping through a json response and I'm trying to use the counter (var i) to say `data.newarray[i].time+i` so with each loop the next array is chosen and the time also increases in number. So 1st loop will spit out `data.newarray[0].time0` then `data.newarray[1].time1` then `data.newarray[2].time2` and so on. The bit that is currently failing is my concatenation `time+i` at the end. How do I format this to work?

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
for(var i=0; i<data.newarray.length; i++)
{
    alert(data.newarray[i].time+i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access variable property names by using the quoted notation: `obj['prop']` instead of `obj.prop`.

The solution is:

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
for(var i=0; i<data.newarray.length; i++)
{
    alert(data.newarray[i]['time'+i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.newarray.length; i++) {
    alert(data.newarray[i]['time'+i]);
}
```